# Is it possible to load a DataSet using a multiple result set?

Tags: c#

Is it possible to load a DataSet using a multiple result set? Please see the commented out code for my attempt.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DataSetPractice
{
    public class Class2
    {
        public void Main()
        {
            var connString = @"Server=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Database=Database1;Trusted_Connection=True;";



            using (var con = new SqlConnection(connString))
            {
                con.Open();

                using var cmd = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT * FROM Customer;", con);
                using var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                DataTable customerDT = new DataTable("Customer");
                ds.Tables.Add(customerDT);
                ds.Load(reader, LoadOption.OverwriteChanges, new[] { customerDT});

                //using var cmd = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT * FROM Customer; SELECT * FROM ORDER", con);
                //using var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                //DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                //DataTable customerDT = new DataTable("Customer");
                //DataTable orderDT = new DataTable("Order");
                //ds.Tables.Add(customerDT);
                //ds.Tables.Add(orderDT);
                //ds.Load(reader, LoadOption.OverwriteChanges, new[] { customerDT, orderDT });

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for a sql data adapter:

```cs
    var query = @"SELECT * FROM Customer; SELECT * FROM [ORDER]";
    var sqlAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(query, con);
    var ds = new DataSet();
    sqlAdapter.Fill(ds);
```

Note: using keywords as the name of tables or columns is a bad idea.

Comment: i'm getting the following error on the `.Fill` `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ORDER'.'`  Do I need something in the connection string that tells it to accept multiple result sets?

Comment: @rod: Order is a keyword, use [order] instead

Comment: nice! that was a subtle bug.